# Something went wrong, please try again from BotFramework MessagingExtesion

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I've been working on implementing a bot for MS Teams connecting to our application, using the BotFramework v4, and C# (Web API library).  I've registered the bot in azure and have successfully gotten the chat portion of the bot working correctly.

However, when I go to search for items from the messaging extension I get the above error of `Something went wrong. Please try again.`  I have stepped through the code and from the server side code it appears I am returning the correct responses, however when I inspect the request from the Teams web client, the response is empty.

[image]

[image]

From the Bot side of the code, I have it implemented as follows

```cs
protected override async Task<MessagingExtensionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, MessagingExtensionQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     var text = query?.Parameters?[0]?.Value as string ?? string.Empty;
     if (text == "true" && query?.Parameters?[0]?.Name == "initialRun")
          return new MessagingExtensionResponse { ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult { Type = "message", Text = "Please enter your search term above" } };
     else 
          return new MessagingExtensionResponse { ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult { Type = "message", Text = "Not the initial run" } };
}
```

and the Controller

```cs
public BotController(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IBot bot)
{
     _adapter = adapter;
     _bot = bot;
}

public async Task Messages()
{
     await _adapter.ProcessAsync(ActionContext.Request, ActionContext.Request.CreateResponse(), _bot);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else running into the same problem, if you are dealing with the BotFramework from ASP.NET WebApi, you need to make sure you are returning the response correctly from the messages endpoint.

i.e. The following routine in the controller

```cs
public async Task Messages()
{
     await _adapter.ProcessAsync(ActionContext.Request, ActionContext.Request.CreateResponse(), _bot);
}
```

needs to turn into

```cs
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Messages()
{
     var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
     await _adapter.ProcessAsync(ActionContext.Request, response, _bot);
     return response;
}
```